# Clean way in PHP to split string on paragraphs. Twist: Delimiters unknown

Tags: php

I'm running a WordPress plugin which processes the content and inserts something after X number of paragraphs. Right now my code is pretty barbaric. Sample:

```
$del = '</p>';
$para_count = substr_count($html, $del);

if($para_count == 0) {
    $del = "\r\n\r\n";
    $para_count = substr_count($html, $del); # echo "1";
}

if($para_count == 0) {
    $del = "\n\n\n\n";
    $para_count = substr_count($html, $del); # echo "2";
}

if($para_count == 0) {
    $del = '
';
    $para_count = round(substr_count($html, $del) / 2); # echo "3";
}       

if($para_count == 0) {
    $del = '<br/><br/>';
    $para_count = substr_count($html, $del); # echo "4";
} 

if($para_count == 0) {
    $del = '<br><br>';
    $para_count = substr_count($html, $del); # echo "5";
}

if($para_count == 0) {
    $del = '<br /><br />';
    $para_count = substr_count($html, $del); # echo "6";
}

if($para_count == 0) {
    return "<div class='display:none'><!-- NO DELIMETER FOUND --></div>".$html;
}
```

What's the best way to find paragraph delimiters when the source is unknown? Can I reduce my script to a simpler bit of code which may be more accurate?

Comment: If delimiters can be mixed, you could use `preg_split()`. Logically, it is right that delimiters can be mixed.

Comment: Example of how I'd use that? I've never used that before. Can I feed the regex an array? I'd only want it to split once, not more, so if it finds a `<p>`, I want it to stop processing and not look for more.